# How can I import a MySQL database from one version of MAMP to another?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I was working on a WordPress website using MAMP, but then my computer died. Luckily the hard drive was fine, and I have put it into an enclosure and am currently working with it plugged into my work laptop as an external drive.

I just copied and pasted the WordPress directory over from my old hard drive onto my work computer. Now I want to take the database from the old version of MAMP and import it into the version of MAMP/phpMyAdmin that I have on my work computer. I'm not sure how I would do this without overwriting all the database content I currently have on my work laptop. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Are the tables of the old database MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: Are you trying to restore to the same version of MySQL  as you were using on the broken system?

Comment: ___Silly question I know___ But did you take a backup (Export) or the database before the system broke?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no idea about MYISAM or INNODB, how do I find out? And no, I would like to simply take the database from the old version of MAMP and run it on the version I have on my work computer.

Comment: And no, I didn't take a backup. But it should be on my hard drive, right?

Comment: If they were MYISAM it would be a Lot easier than if they were INNODB (probably)

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to find out which they are, but no luck so far; would you please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look in the `data`folder. There should be a folder with the name of each of your databases. Look inside the folder for the DB you are interested in and tell me what extensions the files in there have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193155/discussion-between-argoncobalt-and-riggsfolly).